# AngularJS: When to write controller vs show/hide divs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, single-page-application

I am not sure of the usual best practices of when to write a new controller vs when to use show/hide divs.

For instance, I assume you would use a single controller with show/hide divs on a registration form where you need to show different messages after submitting the form, still staying on the same controller. In this case, you need to setup custom routing (maybe UI-Router?) to get the proper back-forward functionality.

On the otherhand, if you have a user settings page with multiple forms. I would assume each form having a different controller.

What are the guidelines in deciding when to use which? I'm looking for a guide./tutorial on where things fit in with MVC model.

Comment: I doubt such a guide/tutorial exists. Typically you would use a single controller per model. Be that model a simple object or complex object with nested data. And then you ngShow/ngHide/ngIf to either display or hide parts of your model based on state. A Wizard implementation might be an example of where you show/hide with a single controller.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a controller is strictly to set up a scope and expose stuff to the view through the scope. So in order for you to use the show/hide you need something to evaluate against and this is the job of the controllers scope you have set up.

Now how you choose to set up the scope or just to use the rootScope is up to you - but rootScope is frowned upon as its like a global variable.

But looking at your question when to use a new controller vs when to use show/hide, I really don't understand how this could ever be a real choice as these two features - controllers and show/hide - accomplish two separate things.

**show/hide** - I assume ng-show and ng-hide are both directives that modify the html that is shown.

**controllers**  - Don't have any business in the angular way of doing things modifying the html. They may only expose the value that the show/hide directives can check against.